# How to Package ADB tool within an Android App

Tags: android, adb

I know that it's possible the [ADB-Shell](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.standardadb) app already does this.

However, I'm not able to find any resources which describe how to do this. I'm looking for either an answer on how to do this or a guide/resource where I can do something like that. Or even perhaps something where I can compile the adb tool to run on Android.

Afterthought: Is it possible to run adb by simply copying the linux platform-tools file into the app/external directory and executing from there?

Comment: The app external directory is on the "sdcard" section which is mounted as noexec. So you can not execute anything from that path or one of it's subdirectories. When packaging adb I would check if there is a matching termux package that can be used.

Comment: @Robert I'm not familiar with TerMux but a quick look at their packages shows that adb is not part of it.

Comment: May be not an official package. But when I search for `termux adb` I get teo GitHub projects providing adb, and I think one even with instructions how to build the package on your own.

Comment: @Robert thanks, I think that answers my question. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I'd like to suggest you trying Shizuku API to be able to execute adb command in your Android app as well.